# Tail application for windows that will track a file across newly created folders

Tags: windows, log-files, tail

I am working with a product, that every time its windows service is restarted, it creates a new folder with date and timestamp, and starts logging into files in this folder.

I am looking for a tail program, that will allow me to tail the "MyLog.log" file across these new folders.

Like this pseudo pattern:  c:\log*\mylog.log

A match for the last created file matching that pattern would be a good match.

Anyone know such a tail?

Comment: Recommendations are off topic for SF. Try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with PowerShell:

```
$LatestLogFile = Get-ChildItem c:\log*\mylog.log | Sort-Object lastwritetime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

Get-Content $LatestLogFile -Wait
```

This should ensure that it always grabs the latest written log file if more than one are found.

It's worth noting though that this won't find a newer log file that's generated until the script is rerun.